# Debug Current Instruction Pointer color is not changing on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, background-color

I would like to change Debug Current Instruction Pointer color progrmatically instead of from Text Editor -see the image below.

I have added the extension which declared on eclipse wiki. But nothing changes..

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
  <specification
        annotationType="org.eclipse.debug.ui.currentIP"
        colorPreferenceKey="currentIPColor"
        colorPreferenceValue="255,217,0"
        highlightPreferenceKey="currentIPHighlight"
        highlightPreferenceValue="true"
        label="Debug Current Instruction Pointer"
        overviewRulerPreferenceKey="currentIPOverviewRuler"
        overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
        presentationLayer="6"
        textPreferenceKey="currentIPIndication"
        textPreferenceValue="false"
        verticalRulerPreferenceKey="currentIPVerticalRuler"
        verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"
        textStylePreferenceKey="currentIPTextStyle"
        textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
        includeOnPreferencePage="false">
  </specification>
```

[image]

Comment: This has already been declared by the org.eclipse.debug.ui plugin, you can't override the settings just by declaring it again. You may be able to do something with the `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.MarkerAnnotationPreferences` class, but you will have to do a lot of research to work out how it is used and what to do.

Comment: Humm i was thinking maybe playing around with IMarker would help but it also didnt.. @greg-449

Comment: Other than asking what problem this solves since there might be a better/supported way, it's just plain *rude* to tamper with another plug-in's preferences.